# Is it possible create/update data into Dataverse from external system?

Tags: integration, powerapps, webapi, dataverse

Is it possible to create/update data in Dataverse tables using Dataverse Web API from an external system like Oracle, SAP, Salesforce, etc. If not Dataverse Web API, any other option available? We are working on an integration project where one of the requirement is to update data from an external system to Dataverse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Dataverse Web API supports CRUD so you can integrate Dataverse with external systems using the API